# What is wrong with my code for CodeHS 8.3.7: Exclamat!on Po!nts?

Tags: python

The problem with my code is that instead of replacing "i" with "!", it adds the "!", keeps the "i" and removes the letter after "i". How do I fix my code?

This is my code right now:

```
my_string = input("Enter text: ")
my_list = list(my_string)
for item in my_list:
    if item == "i":
        print "!"
        my_list.remove("i")
    print item
(" ").join(my_list)
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you're trying to do here - should the string created at the end be the same as `my_string` except with `"i"` replaced by `"!"` and spaces between every character? Because you never add a `"!"` to `my_list`. Or are you just trying to print `my_string` but with every `"i"` replaced by a `"!"`?

Comment: `my_list = [x if x != 'i' else '!' for x in my_string]`

Comment: The way that it is supposed to work is that you give input and if there is an `"i"`, it will be replaced with an `"!"`. However, this code adds the `"!"`, keeps the `"i"` and removes the letter after `"i"`. I need this fixed so `"i"` is replaced with `"!"`.

Comment: Words are way more fun when you replace the letter ‘i’ with an exclamation point! Write a program that asks the user for a string and then prints the same string with every lowercase i replaced with an exclamation point. Your program should: Convert the initial string to a list Use a for loop to go through your list element by element Whenever you see a lowercase i, replace it with an exclamation point in the list Print the stringified version of the list when your for loop is finished Here’s what an example run of your program might look like: `Enter text: I like music. I l!ke mus!c.`

Comment: That's what the instructions say.

Comment: I don't see how the code you've shown could be doing the behavior you describe seeing. The string produced by the final line of your code would be the original text, with all `'i'` removed, and spaces inserted. For example, `'this'` becomes `'t h s'`. You certainly never add any exclamation points. Are you sure you're showing us the same code you're testing?

Comment: **What is wrong with my code** is the same as **Can someone help me** and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). Review [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I would use `my_list.insert(position,x)`

Python has really good documentation on the data structure `list` here!
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html